# Integer 26 has been treated as end of file, how can I avoid this?

Tags: c, windows, eof, fread

When I am using `fread()` to read the integer array one by one, it stops at 26. I understand 26 is `eof`, but how can I avoid this?

```
int data[] = { 3,8,10,62,11,40,20,6,26,7,26,20,29,31,33,10,34,37,37,33,50,55,52,59,53,49,53,8,57,16,58,20 };
int count = fwrite(data, sizeof(int), 32, fp);
```

Edit:
plateform is windows.

fopen with mode "rb" will sovle this issue, thanks for the comments.

Comment: Because on some older file systems, a textfile uses `0x1A` (`26`) as an actual EOF marker, part of the file. If you want the value `26` in a text file, it won't be in a single byte but in two bytes, for example `0x32 0x36`.

Comment: Did you open `fp` with the mode `b`?

Comment: What is your platform?

Comment: Please provide [mcve] and the question might get reopened.

Comment: Four upvotes for a closed question? This isn't a voting ring is it?

Comment: The question includes enough information and code to answer.  Voting to re-open.  The information in the very first comments could be expanded into an answer that future visitors would likely find helpful, especially since (surprisingly) a quick search doesn't show an extant question providing useful information for this common conundrum.